# Scanning project to view code coverage php

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage

I have a php project and want to scan it to view code coverage.

I'm using AppSpider to scan my application links and I want to see how much code has covered during this process. Can I do it?

Comment: You do understand what [code coverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage) is, don't you? It's the proportion of your code that is covered by your tests.... so if you don't have tests, then code coverage is 0%..... no need to scan anything to work that out

Comment: Checkout a great example here: https://github.com/codecov/example-php

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write unit test cases to be able to generate a code coverage report.  Being able to generate a coverage report will rely on:

- whether there are any tests to begin with
- the test suite/tool they use
- xdebug being installed and enabled (*from memory*)

If you do not have a test suite then by definition your code coverage will be 0 anyway.

If you use PHPUnit, you can generate a coverage report directly, they've some [handy documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html) on the matter.

### For PHPUnit

[This guide](http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/04/08/reporting-code-coverage-with-phpunit-and-xdebug) might be helpful.  Specifically:

```
phpunit --coverage-html ./report MyTests.php
```

Then you can load up `./report/index.html` to view the HTML report.

It might be worth generating the `--coverage-clover ./report/coverage.xml` report which can be imported and viewed by many other tools.

### For behavioural tests

In light of your comment/update, you may find [this write up](http://tech.vg.no/2014/01/21/generating-code-coverage-of-behat-tests/) useful.  Whilst it does use behat as the driver of requests, you could adapt a similar technique using AppSpider instead.  Note that this isn't strictly the most appropriate way to generate 'code coverage' reports (as outlined in the post).

Comment: I'm using AppSpider to scan my application links and I want to see how much code has covered during this process. Can I do it?

Comment: As per my updated answer addressing behavioural tests you could use a similar model to Behat code coverage - but it is unlikely to be something you'll get _out of the box_ so to speak.